# Can I run a Main class within the JVM of JBoss AS?

Tags: java, jboss, jvm, ejb, local

I'm trying to test an EJB with `@Local` (instead of `@Remote`) in a Main class, but I can't figure out how (or if) can I run a java class in the same JVM that JBoss AS runs.

With `@Remote` it works. 
`@Local` works only if I test it in a Servlet (cuz it runs in the same JVM with JBoss).

Answer (score 0):

Stick whatever the main method does into a non static method on the Main class, then in the main() method create an instance of Main, and invoke the method (am assuming arguments are not used). Then start up the jmx console, find your EJB, and invoke the new non static method.

Why you would want to do all this is an interesting question.